# Testing a discrete random variable for uniformity through some order statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I would like to develop a simple test for the uniform distribution of a discrete random variable, but I did not manage to find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/is-there-a-simple-test-for-uniform-distributions) the relevant informations, and I am pretty sure that someone will be able to help me.

Let us assume that an experiment has $n$ possible outcomes, $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, all with the same probability.
Once we perform $n^3$ experiments, we denote as $M$ the number of experiments leading to the most successful outcome, $L$ the number of experiments leading to the least successful outcome.

1. What is the average value of $M-L$?
2. What is the distribution of $M-L$?

I would guess that the typical outcome has frequency $n^2\pm cn$, such that $M-L$ is expected to be $2cn$ for some explicit constant $c$.
I am not really sure about the second point, I am just guessing a Beta distribution of some sort.

Comment: Do you want exact answers, or are you also interested in asymptotic results for $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @joriki: asymptotics (or just the exact value of $c$) are fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the distribution of $M-L$ is closely approximated by a suitable beta-binomial distribution with parameters $(a, b, n^3)$ for suitably large $n$.  The quality of this approximation is poor when $n \le 4$ but improves substantially thereafter.  I did some simulation to empirically determine values of $a$ and $b$ as a function of $n$, but with limited success in discerning a pattern.  These may be summarized in the following table:
$$\begin{array}{c|cc} 
n & a & b \\
\hline
  2 & 1.5071 & 4.2193 \\
 3 & 6.66791 & 28.872 \\
 4 & 11.1539 & 75.7145 \\
 5 & 14.9201 & 145.694 \\
 6 & 18.1219 & 239.632 \\
 7 & 20.8874 & 357.923 \\
 8 & 23.26 & 500.029 \\
 9 & 25.3165 & 665.664 \\
 10 & 27.2136 & 857.58 \\
 11 & 28.9557 & 1075.75 \\
 12 & 30.5506 & 1320.17 \\
 13 & 31.9877 & 1589.23 \\
 14 & 33.4234 & 1890.14 \\
 15 & 34.7004 & 2214.84 \\
 16 & 35.892 & 2566.21 \\
 17 & 37.1326 & 2954.86 \\
 18 & 38.2098 & 3363.76 \\
 19 & 39.3065 & 3808.03 \\
 20 & 40.338 & 4280.45 \\
\end{array}$$
I post this as an invitation for others to see if they can tease out a pattern in these parameter estimates, keeping in mind that these are empirically derived.

Comment: (+1) precious data indeed. The turnpoint $n=5$ is not surprising either, since it also represents the instant in which a binomial distribution starts to be closely approximated by a gaussian distribution.