# Mathematics of Random Number Generation

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms, random

I am interested in learning more about Random Number Generation. Recently, I found out about an algorithm called "RANDU" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU), which was an early algorithm for generating random numbers.

Using the R language, I implemented it below:

```
v = rep(0,100)
v[1]=3
for (j in 1:100) {
v[j+1]=(65539*v[j])%%(2^31)
}

    i = 1:101

range01 <- function(x, ...){(x - min(x, ...)) / (max(x, ...) - min(x, ...))}
      
    rand_data = data.frame(i,v)
    rand_data$int_version = range01(rand_data$v)

 head(rand_data)
  i        v  int_version
1 1        3 0.000000e+00
2 2   196617 9.201486e-05
3 3  1179675 5.520835e-04
4 4  5308497 2.484362e-03
5 5 21233907 9.937413e-03
6 6 79626969 3.726522e-02
    

plot(rand_data$v, type = "b", main = "100 Random Real Numbers with Randu")
```

[image]

Naturally, this lead me to the following question:

- How do we know that these 100 numbers are truly random - Is there some mathematical proof for this?
- Why does this RANDU algorithm work - Is there some mathematical proof for this?

I tried to look into this, but I couldn't find a straight answer. Can someone please provide any comments?

Thank you!

Note: Apparently you can use the Chi-Square Test to find out if a random sequence of numbers has a "uniform distribution" (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406406/test-of-uniform-distribution-using-ks-test-and-chi-square-in-r, [Is there a simple test for uniform distributions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/is-there-a-simple-test-for-uniform-distributions) ... but I am not sure why the Chi-Square Test can detect if random numbers have a uniform distribution). I performed this test in R:

```
ks.test(rand_data$int_version, "punif", min(rand_data$int_version), max(rand_data$int_version))

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  rand_data$int_version
D = 0.079507, p-value = 0.5457
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Based on these results, the p-value is significantly greater than a standard tolerance level (e.g. alpha = 0.05) - therefore, there is sufficient statistical evidence to accept the Null Hypothesis and conclude that these random numbers correspond to a uniform distribution.

Comment: R... aka Rhit....

Comment: They are not truly random, but instead pseudo-random.  And the algorithm has flaws such as that illustrated in the 3D plot in the Wikipedia article

Comment: Even defining what it means to be "random" is very tricky, but, being a deterministic process, we usually don't call it random.

Comment: Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming: RANDU is a linear congruential random number generator, and a pretty bad one at that.

Comment: @ Henry: Thank you for your reply! I am having some trouble understanding the difference between pseudo-random and random numbers. It seems like pseudo-random numbers are random numbers that are generated using a deterministic machine (e.g. a computer), and this is implies that there might be some room for "non-randomness" ... but truly random are generated from some non-deterministic process (e.g. decimal numbers in atmospheric pressure readings) and are generally considered to be more "random". Is this correct?

Comment: @ Henry: I read the Wikipedia article and also read that this algorithm has flaws, but I was not able to fully understand these flaws and why these flaws are produced. Could you please help me understand this? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews: Thank you for your reply! "a deterministic process, we usually don't call it random" - why is this so? Thank you!

Comment: @ gnasher729: Thank you for your reply! Can you please explain why RANDU is not good? thank you so much!

Comment: @the_candyman : haha!

Comment: @ Moo: this looks very complicated!

Comment: pick a book on pseudorandom numbers, it will clarify all your questions, by example the book of Oded Goldreich

Comment: @  Masacroso: Thank you! I will look into it!