# Get $\pi$ decimals manually

Tags: numerical-methods, pi

I know that there was a guy that could get 100 decimal digits of $\pi$ before computers were able to get thousands.

How did the guy do that?

Comment: At least two ways: Machin's formulae or the arithmetic-geometric mean. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [John Machin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Machin) combined the formula 
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=4\cot^{-1}5-\cot^{-1}239$$
with the Taylor series expansion for the inverse tangent in order to compute $\pi$ to 100 decimal places.

A previous record was due to [Abraham Sharp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Sharp) who used an arcsine series to find 72 decimal digits.

Answer (score 4):

This page on the [chronology of pi](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/Pi_chronology.html) contains many useful notes on how the pre-computer era calculations of $\pi$ were performed.

Answer (score 1):

See also [Pi: A Source Book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/history+of+mathematics/book/978-0-387-20571-7).

Answer (score 1):

Check this, you can find n-th PI digit without computing previous ones :) 
It was a big surprise when this formula was discovered.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula