# Calculating Pi to a certain length

Tags: pi

Is there quick way to calculate Pi to a certain amount of digits? i.e. If I wanted to calculate pi to say, 35 decimal places, is there a way I could do that? Also, I don't mean finding the digits manually, I more meant is there an algorithm or formula I could have a program run to find pi to an exact length. Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but I just wanted to point out that the "328" in the digits of pi on your profile page should be a "348", somewhere in the 80-90 digit mark.

Comment: Have you looked at related questions like this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297/simple-numerical-methods-for-calculating-the-digits-of-pi

Comment: Yes, there are many different ways to calculate $\pi$ depending on what your requirements are (easy computation by hand, fastest computer algorithm, simplest to program...). Maybe you could elaborate on the context.